# Proof of $x^p$ sub/super additive?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

What is the easiest proof that $x^p$ is sub (or super) additive for  $p>1$ (or $p<1$) and $p\in \mathbb R$.

This is the same as showing for  $a,b\geq 0$
$$a^p+b^p\leq (a+b)^p,$$

when $p\geq 1$. It is possible to take a logarithm and compare the Taylor series to prove the claim, but is there anything simpler?

Comment: Binomial theorem? We don't care about the terms $ka^ib^j$ for both $i, j\ne p$ anyway

Comment: @Divide1918 $p$ is real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a,b >0, p>1$, let $f(x)=(1+x)^p-x^p \implies f'(x)=p(1+x)^{p-1}-px^{p-1}=px^{p-1}[(1+1/x)^{p-1}-1] \ge 0$  for $x >0, p>1$, so $f(x)$ is an increasing function, hence $f(a/b)\ge f(0)$
$$\implies (1+a/b)^p-(a/b)^p \ge 1 \implies (a+b)^p-a^p \ge b^p$$
Finally, $$(a+b)^p \ge a^p+b^p, ~~if~~ a,b >0, p>1$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $p>1$. You can define for $x\geq 0$
$$f(x) = (a+x)^p\,;\qquad g(x) = a^p + x^p\,.$$
Clearly $f(0) = g(0)$. Now take the derivatives.

$$f'(x) = p(a+x)^{p-1}\,;\qquad g'(x)=p x^{p-1}\,.$$

Since $a>0$ and $p>1$ it's clear that for all positive $x$ you have $f'(x)\geq g'(x)$. This ends the proof for $p>1$ since for all $x\geq 0$ you'll have $f(x)\geq g(x)$.

For $p<1$ you can proceed in the same way and get the opposite inequality.

Answer (score -1):

We have that the $p$-norm is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ when $1\leqslant p < +\infty$. This means that $\lVert.\rVert_p$ is subadditive. So let's define $a=(x,0)$ and $b=(0,y)$. The subadditivity means that
$$\lVert a + b \rVert = (|x|^p + |y|^p)^{1/p}\leqslant |x|+|y|=\lVert a \rVert + \lVert b \rVert$$
Which is exactly what we wanted:
$$|x|^p+|y|^p\leqslant (|x|+|y|)^p$$

Comment: Probably was downvoted since it is a bit circular...

Comment: @Tony I think it's not circular. You can prove that the $p$-norm is a norm on $\mathbb{K}^n$ by showing that the unit ball generated by the $p$-norm is convex. To prove this, you just need to use the fact that the function $t \mapsto t^p$ is convex.